# Meteor 0.9.0 Error: EACCES, permission denied '/Users/Jasper/.meteorsession'

Tags: meteor

After updating to meteor 0.9.0 I get the following error when launching an app to localhost

```
 Error: EACCES, permission denied '/Users/Jasper/.meteorsession'
at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:432:18)
at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:289:15)
at readSessionData (/Users/Jasper/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.26.1fmrgj1++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/auth.js:137:24)
at Object.tryRevokeOldTokens (/Users/Jasper/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.26.1fmrgj1++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/auth.js:331:10)
at main.registerCommand.name [as func] (/Users/Jasper/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.26.1fmrgj1++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/commands.js:197:8)
at /Users/Jasper/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.26.1fmrgj1++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/main.js:1212:23
```

Starting the meteor session with sudo meteor fixes this problem but I was wondering what causes this and how it can be fixed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Understanding error message from Meteor.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16453481/understanding-error-message-from-meteor-js)

Comment: You should probably not run Meteor with `sudo` anymore, and use `chown` to make all Meteor files not owned by root.

Answer (score 8):

Just delete the .meteorsession and restart meteor and it will create a new .meteorsession directory.

Run the following code in your terminal:

```
rm -rf /Users/Jasper/.meteorsession
```

Comment: Where would I find the .meteorsession directory? Can't deem to find it